# How to get the correct number of background jobs running, f.ex. $(jobs | wc -l | xargs) returns 1 instead of 0

Tags: bash, background, jobs

I have a jenkins build job that starts processes in the background. I need to write a function that checks wether there are still background processes running. To test it I came up with this:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

function waitForUploadFinish() {
  runningJobs=$(jobs | wc -l | xargs)
  echo "Waiting for ${runningJobs} background upload jobs to finish"

  while [ "$(jobs | wc -l | xargs)" -ne 0 ];do
    echo "$(jobs | wc -l | xargs)"
    echo -n "."     # no trailing newline
    sleep 1
  done
  echo ""
}


for i in {1..3}
do
  sleep $i &
done

waitForUploadFinish
```

The problem is it never comes down to 0. Even when the last `sleep` is done, there is still one job running?

```
mles-MBP:ionic mles$ ./jobs.sh 
Waiting for 3 background upload jobs to finish
3
.2
.1
.1
.1
.1
.1
.1
```

**Why I don't want to use `wait` here**

In the Jenkins build job script where this snippet is for, i'm starting background upload processes for huge files. They don't run for 3 seconds like in the example here with `sleep`. They can take up to 30 minutes to proceed. If I use `wait` here, the user would see something like this in the log:

```
upload huge_file1.ipa & 
upload huge_file2.ipa & 
upload huge_file3.ipa & 
wait
```

They would wonder why is nothing going on?

Instead I want to implement something like this:

```
upload huge_file1.ipa & 
upload huge_file2.ipa & 
upload huge_file3.ipa & 
Waiting for 3 background upload jobs to finish
............
Waiting for 2 background upload jobs to finish
.................
Waiting for 1 background upload jobs to finish
.........
Upload done
```

That's why I need the loop with the current running background jobs.

Comment: If the only purpose of your loop is to wait for all jobs to terminate, then just replace the whole thing with `wait`. If you have a recent version of Bash (Bash≥4.3), you can also use `wait -n` to wait for the next job to terminate. Now, while your design is pretty bad (awful uses of `| wc -l | xargs` and you're not focusing on running jobs nor waiting for jobs to terminate), using `jobs -r` to focus on running jobs should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I expanded my question why I don't want to use `wait` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fixes it:

```
function waitForUploadFinish() {
  runningJobs=$(jobs | wc -l | xargs)
  echo "Waiting for ${runningJobs} background upload jobs to finish"

  while [ `jobs -r | wc -l | tr -d " "` != 0 ]; do 
    jobs -r | wc -l | tr -d " "
    echo -n "."     # no trailing newline
    sleep 1
  done
  echo ""
}
```

Note: you will only count the background processes that are started by this bash script, you will not see the background processes from the starting shell.

As the gniourf_gniourf commented: if you only need to wait and don't need to output then a simple `wait` after the `sleep`s is much simpler.

```
for i in {1..3}; do
  sleep $i &
done

wait
```

Comment: What does `tr -d " "` do? Cut whitespace what I was doing with `xargs`?

Comment: yes, cut whitespaces. xargs is actually for sending output from one command to another, so `tr` fits this purpose better and is just clearer than using `xargs`

Answer (score 2):

Please consider comments made by gniourf_gniourf, as your design is not good to start with.

However, despite a much simpler and more efficient solution being possible, there is the question of why you are seeing what you are seeing.

I modified the first line of your loop, like so :

```
while [ "$(jobs | tee >(cat >&2) | wc -l | xargs)" -ne 0 ];do
```

The `tee` command takes its input and sends it to both standard out and to the file passed as argument.  `>(cat >&2)` is syntax that, to explain it simply, provides a file to the `tee` command, but that file really is a named FIFO and anything written to that file will be sent to standard error, bypassing the pipeline and allowing you to see what `jobs` is spitting out, all while allowing the rest of the pipeline to operate normally.

If you do that, you will notice that the "job" that `jobs` keeps on returning is not a job, but a message stating some other job has finished.  I do not know why it keeps on repeating that, but this is the cause of the problem.

You could replace :

```
while [ "$(jobs | wc -l | xargs)" -ne 0 ];do
```

With :

```
while [ "$(jobs -p | grep "^[0-9]" | wc -l | xargs)" -ne 0 ];do
```

This will cause `jobs` to echo PIDs, and filter out any line that does not begin with a number, so messages will not be counted.

Comment: can you post the "much simpler and more efficient solution" please?